# Magento 1.7: Using a filter to filter products and to change the URL?

Tags: magento, filter

Looking at the [zalando shop](http://www.zalando.de/), you can click through the product categories and the colors for example. The result is a URL like this: http://www.zalando.de/sports-damen-shirts-funktion/_schwarz.pink.lila/ for example.

So looking at the URL its clear what has been clicked, sport shirts for women with colors lila, pink and schwarz (colors are in German). Is this a feature of the Magento Enterprise Edition, or does the Community Edition also support that? I dont really know what to search for, because I lack the name of this feature.

Can anybody tell me how that feature might be called and if its implemented by the shop owners or if its a build in feature?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly should that tell me?

Comment: product url, you get full url this way: Mage::getBaseUrl().$product->getProductUrl();

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what Im asking ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using some custom module for layered navigation. Because in native Magento filtered link contains pairs of `attribute_code = attribute_value`.
You can check in Google more information about [Magento SEO Layered Navigation](https://www.google.com.ua/search?aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=magento%20seo%20layered%20navigation).

Comment: Yeah, that goes into the right direction, let me check your link. Ill be back ...